# Replace symbols in a string with conflicting keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, lookup

I need a translator, that have a dictionary with keys like
`'s': 'd'`
and
`'sch': 'b'`
.
That's a rough example, but the point is, when i have an input word like `"schto"`, it needs to replace it as `"bkr"`, substitute `'sch'` to `'b'`. BUT there are the key `'s'`, thus it translates the word as `"dnokr"`, leave out and never lookup for `'sch'`, because there the key with the symbol `'s'` and it translates it first before `'sch'`. What is a workaround here to replace the input word with the key `'sch'` first, not with separate 's', 'c', and 'h'?

Here is the example of the code.

```
newdict = {'sch': 'b', 'sh': 'q', 'ch': 'w', 's': 'd', 'c': 'n', 'h': 'o', 't': 'k', 'o': 'r'}

code = input("Type: ")
code = "".join([newdict[w] for w in code])
print(code)
```

Comment: Okay, and what is the rule that tells you that you should use the `sch` key even though `s` is also available? For example, are you always looking for the longest match at a current point in the string? Are you looking for matches that will minimize the total number of lookups? Something else?

Comment: There is no question in this question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python version 3.4+, then dictionary maintain the insertions order of keys. And hence you can achieve this using `str.replace()` while iterating over `dict.items()`.

It'll **recursively update the strings based on mapping**. For example, if `'h'` is replaced by `'o'`, then `'o'` will be replaced by `'r'`.

```
newdict = {'sch': 'b', 'sh': 'q', 'ch': 'w', 's': 'd', 'c': 'n', 'h': 'o', 't': 'k', 'o': 'r'}
my_word = "schto"

for k, v in newdict.items():
    my_word = my_word.replace(k, v)
```

where `my_word` will give you your desired string as `'bkr'`.

Here, since the `dict.items()` maintains the insertion order, *keys* which are defined first will be executed first during the iteration. Hence, you can define the priority of your rules by defining the keys you want to give precedence by declaring them before the other keys.

Comment: Even if it works in this specific case, it is rather fragile, as any replacement risks being replaced again if any part of the replacing string appears later in the dict.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Agreed. And that was intentional by me, assuming that's the desired result. Because it is not clear from OP, added a note in my answer to describe this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are greedy by default. If you're using a version of Python in which the insertion-order of key-value pairs in a dictionary are guaranteed, and you insert the key-value pairs in such a way that the longer ones come first, something like this should work for you - `re.sub` takes either a string with which to replace a match, or it takes a callable (function/lambda/whatever), which accepts the current match as an argument, and must return a string with which to replace it:

```
import re

lookup = {
    "sch": "b",
    "sh": "q",
    "s": "d"
}

def replace(match):
    return lookup[match.group()]

pattern = "|".join(lookup)

print(re.sub(pattern, replace, "schush swim"))
```

Output:

```
buq dwim
>>>
```

Comment: Python regexes are not greedy (by default or otherwise) in the sense that they don't favour the longest match. If they did ao, you wouldn't have to worry about key order in the dictionary.

Comment: @rici Greedy may not have been the appropriate term. What I meant was, that the order in which the "sub-patterns" (`sch`, `sh` and `s`) appear in the pattern (`"sch|sh|s"` for example), matters. In a case where the pattern consists of a bunch of joined ORs, such as this one, the first seen instance will have precedence, probably because of some kind of short-circuiting I imagine.

Comment: "Greedy" means "takes as much as possible". Python regexes have greedy (by default) repetition operators: `S*` means "as many S as possible while still matching the rest"; `S*?` means "as few S as possible while still matching the rest. You could say that alternations are matched *eagerly* (the first plausible match wins) but since it still has the requirement that the rest of the pattern matches, it's not really dogmatically eager :-) (Try `re.compile('(ab|a)bc').match('abc')`, where the success of the match shows that it fell back to the second alternative.)

Comment: In fact, the Python docs explicitly say "In other words, the `|` operator is never greedy", although I think the docs are misleading about fallbacks. But anyway, there's no "by default" for eagerness, since there is no way of requesting a longest match.